# nil user gets logged in if password is incorrect after an actual current user signs out

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift3, xcode8

Alright, so I am making this app which requires the user to sign in and also logout if they want. When the user taps the logout button, it takes them back to the login screen and logs the user out. After performing a few checks, The user is logged out fully and user = nil

The problem I am having is, after the user logs out, if someone else wants to log in, or the same user wants to log back in and the password is not correct, it informs the user that the password is not correct, but after the alert is dismissed, a "nil" user is signed in. The app crashes when trying to do anything inside the app passed this point.
I have placed "print" checks to see if any user is getting signed in with wrong passwords and the only return I get is "nil"

Before anyone mentions it, I have already made sure that PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() is off.

I will note that if the app is fully closed and reopened, it won't sign any user in. It just lets them know the password is incorrect and they can try again.

```
      @IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {

    PFUser.logOutInBackground()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "logoutSegue", sender: self)

}
```

Above is my set up for the logout button. I have tried the basic, "PFUser.logOut() and also the PFUser.logOutInBackground()

Both of which off er the same thing in my code. I will add information if requested. Please help!!!!

Comment: you should edit your first post and upload the code snippet of when the user is being authenticated

Comment: Are you running your own Parse server? You know Parse.com is gone, right?

Comment: I am aware Parse.com is gone. However, Parse is open source. It works...just a little tricker to set it up. I rather use Parse then Firebase.

Comment: Is it possible the issue is in your login logic?  If you see an error with wrong password, do you handle it correctly or do you move on?

Comment: Being told your problem is about logining back into the app, I guess the wrong code is somewhere around log in, not log out. Thus, can you share the code snip of log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your logic. My logic is as follows:

```
// MARK: - LOGOUT BUTTON
@IBAction func logoutButt(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: APP_NAME,
        message: "Are you sure you want to logout?",
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in            
        PFUser.logOutInBackground(block: { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                // Show the Login screen
                let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! Login
                self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    })


    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })

    alert.addAction(ok); alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It is true that he should do a null check. However, he is actually logging out successfully, so I guess we can ignore logging out securely. This is of course my guess, may be wrong as well.

Comment: Could be, but he hasn't posted his login logic for me to comment.

Comment: I figured it out...so...my alert that I had created for the login controller was set up wrong. In short...I was using "self.alert" instead of "alert.alert" which is why it was logging the user back in as nil user.

Comment: nevertheless, i strongly suggest you look at my logic and ensure you check if nill. Glad u came right!

Comment: I did a check if nil and everything worked great. Very pleased. Thanks for the response!